# Set value if value is not nil Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby

Is there a nicer way of doing the following in Ruby?:

```
user.some_property = something if !something.nil?
```

So, set `user.some_property` to the value of `something` if `something` is not `nil`. I need to make that check or Rails throws an error.

Thanks

Comment: Note, I know I can do `user.some_property = something if something` but I think there could be even cleaner, like an unwrap

Comment: Well, substituting `unless something.nil?` for `if !something.nil?` is a little cleaner.  Both are so readable though! Why shorten them?

Comment: The `unless` version reads like a sentence.

Comment: maybe this `user.some_property ||= something`

Comment: That's incorrect @waqarmirza, that's set user.some_property if user.some_property is nil

Comment: Is there possibility of `something` being `false`?

Comment: Close voted because the question is unclear. I have not idea how `user.some_property = something if something` works as expected while `user.some_property = something || user.some_property` does not.

Comment: @sawa the former calls `some_property=` only if `something` is truthy, whereas the latter calls `some_property=` in any case. The OP needs to clarify whether this is relevant.

Comment: @Stefan Right. Always calling `user.some_property=` may make it slightly inefficient, but that should be insignificant. What may matter is that `user.some_property` is heavy and has memoization, for example. But since the OP said nothing about the nature of these methods, I assumed that it is a simple attribute reader method.

Comment: Ok, added some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the obvious choice is

```
user.some_property = something unless something.nil?
```

But if you do this, you need to think about the consequences of `user.some_property` potentially being `nil`.  A good way to handle this might be a default value for `some_property` on initialization

Comment: Guess this is the best I'll get. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, but I can't see why:

```
user.some_property = something unless something.nil?
```

is preferable to:

```
user.some_property = something if something
```

Unless you want some_property to be set as false when something = false rather than nil.